# Add images to rank 1, 2 and 3 with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, rank

im trying to add 3 images to my PHP code, for people who are rank 1, 2 and 3.
But I can't seem to get it to work

I got 3 images called gold_medal.png, silver_medal.png and bronze_medal.png

here is my code

```
<?php 
        //Database Info 
        $host = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'; 
        $user = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
        $pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $db = 'hall_of_fame'; 

<table> 
    <tr> 
    <th>Rank</th> 
    <th>Player</th> 
    <th>Donation</th> 
    </tr>
<?php
//Connect to the SQL server and select the database... 
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Couldn\'t connect to the MySQL server.'); 
mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

$rowsPerPage = 10;
// if $_GET['page'] defined, use it as page number

function steam2friend($steam_id){ 
$steam_id = strtolower($steam_id); 
    if(substr($steam_id,0,7) == 'steam_0'){ 
        $tmp = explode(':',$steam_id); 
            if((count($tmp)==3) && is_numeric($tmp[1]) && is_numeric($tmp[2])){ 
                return bcadd((($tmp[2]*2)+$tmp[1]),'76561197960265728'); 
            }else{ 
            return false; 
            } 
            }else{ 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hof_players ORDER BY donation DESC LIMIT $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hof_players ORDER BY donation DESC LIMIT $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());
$Rank = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
            echo "<tr align=center>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $Rank++;
            echo "</td>";
            if(!empty($row['name']) && $row['name'] != ' '){ 
            echo "<td>" . '<i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i>' . '<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.steam2friend($row['steamid']).'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'</a>' . '<i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i>' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            else{ 
            echo "<td>" . 'No Player In DB' . "</td>"; 
            }
            if(!empty($row['donation']) && $row['donation'] != ' '){ 
            echo "<td>" . $row['donation'] . '&#160;' . 'DKK' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            else{ 
            echo "<td>" . 'No donations in DB' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            echo "</tr>"; 
            }
}
?>
</table>
```

I have set up a test site here where you can see it http://clanroyal.dk/hof_test.php

now what I want is for rank 1 to have the gold medal next to his name rank 2 the silver and rank 3 the bronze.

Im totally clueless about this one, so any help would really be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling 2 different SQL queries which produce the same results?

The nested `while` loop `$row` variable is overwriting the original, get rid of the 2nd `$result2` querys and try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hof_players ORDER BY donation DESC LIMIT $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());
$Rank = 1;

$rankImages = array(
    1   =>   'gold_medal.png',
    2   =>   'silver_medal.png',
    3   =>   'bronze_medal.png'
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo "<tr align=center>";
    echo "<td>";

    if($Rank>0 && $Rank<=3){
        echo $Rank . ' <img src="' . $rankImages[$Rank] . '">';
    } else {
        echo $Rank . ' - ';
    }

    echo "</td>";

    $rank += 1;

    if(!empty($row['name']) && $row['name'] != ' ' && $row[0])
    { 
        echo "<td>" . '<i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i> <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' . steam2friend($row['steamid']) . '" target="_blank">' . $row['name'] . '</a><i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i></td>'; 
    } else { 
        echo "<td>No Player In DB</td>"; 
    }

    if(!empty($row['donation']) && $row['donation'] != ' ')
    { 
        echo "<td>" . $row['donation'] . "&#160;DKK</td>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<td>No donations in DB</td>"; 
    } 

    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

In addition, you should get out of the habit of using `mysql_*` functionality. Its depreciated, try using either [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your response. Im trying your code and it works, the only issue is it dosn't show the Rank number now under the Rank row, so the first 3 have the images and the rest just have nothing

Comment: I got it working by editing your code alittle :) so thanks for the help!

Comment: @MikkelGlenvig, sorry I forgot to add the rank number with the image, although, glad you've got it working :)

Comment: hmm do you know how to make it only show the images for the first 3 and then after show the numbers? so it would be

Gold
Silver
Bronze
4
5
6 
and so on

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully this should work as you would like

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is put an IF statement in the loop that checks for the value of RANK, and outputs the correct medal.  I've noticed your medal images are quite large, so you might want to shrink them first.

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
            echo "<tr align=center>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $Rank++;
if($Rank == 1)
 echo("<img src=\"gold_medal.png\"/>");
else if ($Rank == 2)
 echo("<img src=\"silver_medal.png\"/>");
else if ($Rank == 3)
 echo("<img src=\"bronze_medal.png\"/>");

            echo "</td>";
            if(!empty($row['name']) && $row['name'] != ' ' && $row[0]){ 
            echo "<td>" . '<i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i>' . '<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.steam2friend($row['steamid']).'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'</a>' . '<i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i>' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            else{ 
            echo "<td>" . 'No Player In DB' . "</td>"; 
            }
            if(!empty($row['donation']) && $row['donation'] != ' '){ 
            echo "<td>" . $row['donation'] . '&#160;' . 'DKK' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            else{ 
            echo "<td>" . 'No donations in DB' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            echo "</tr>"; 
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) I know they are large, I wouldnt shrink em until I got it working ^^

Comment: hmm, with your code it's dosnt show the gold medal, and it put's the silver on rank 1 and bronze on rank 2

Comment: You can either initialize Rank as 0 (which I think you did before I put my answer), or put the code that displays the image right before "echo Rank++;"

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
            echo "<tr align=center>";
            switch($Rank) {
                case 1:
                     echo "<td><img src=\"gold_medal.png\"/></td>";
                     break;
                case 2:
                     echo "<td><img src=\"silver_medal.png\"/></td>";
                     break;
                case 3:
                     echo "<td><img src=\"bronze_medal.png\"/></td>";
                     break;
                default:
                     echo "<td></td>";
                     break;
            }
            echo "<td>";
            echo $Rank++;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $Rank++;
            echo "</td>";
            if(!empty($row['name']) && $row['name'] != ' ' && $row[0]){ 
            echo "<td>" . '<i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i>' . '<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.steam2friend($row['steamid']).'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'</a>' . '<i>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</i>' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            else{ 
            echo "<td>" . 'No Player In DB' . "</td>"; 
            }
            if(!empty($row['donation']) && $row['donation'] != ' '){ 
            echo "<td>" . $row['donation'] . '&#160;' . 'DKK' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            else{ 
            echo "<td>" . 'No donations in DB' . "</td>"; 
            } 
            echo "</tr>"; 
            }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you could do just set the variable $Rank to 0 before the loop, so the Rank is valid till the end of loop, and in the loop, at the beggining increment it with $Rank++, and next to player name do something like this:

```
if ($Rank == 1) echo "<img src='gold_medal.png' />";
if ($Rank == 2) echo "<img src='silver_medal.png' />";
if ($Rank == 3) echo "<img src='bronze_medal.png' />";
```